# Apple CNA, auto-close after authentication?

Tags: ios, macos, wifi, captivenetwork

Trying to achieve `iOS` and `OSX` management
of my Wifi captive hotspot,

I dont manage to fully succeed in:

1. CNA displays, => Done.
2. CNA button *Cancel* becomes *Done* => Done.
3. CNA closes. => **My question: is it possible the CNA automatically Close ?** (or to make it close with a button inside the rendered page into CNA)

How can I manage 3. ? Have you already see this working (CNA autoclosing after authentication) ?

Thanks --

Comment: Offering a bounty in advance is not likely to prompt an early response. Not that it matters: this is off-topic anyway. See [help/on-topic], point #4

Comment: @HoboSapiens I have Edited. Please cancel downvote. Thanks

Comment: Afaik the CNA just check to see if it can access a known website (apple.com?) if it can't then it displays the CNA. Post authentication it checks again - presumably the site now responds correctly and the CNA closes.

Comment: @Paulw11 You are right. I got it, The CNA is here displayed (step 1), but even if after having Logged, all traffic is "opened" to www, it happens **nothing**.

Comment: You should send a redirect back to the same URL that was originally requested by the CNA

Comment: I just tested and even a redirect to another web page causes the "cancel" to change to "done"

Comment: I think you just need to send a HTTP 301 or 307 status

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it. You cannot do that. There is no way, no doc, no witness of it.